# how do i use wait and notify properly

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore, thread-synchronization

I tried making these two threads alternate but I failed. The logic is correct I think but the execution is wrong.  What do i do? It's a producer-consumer problem that I need to do using wait and notify.

Here is the producer class:

```
public class Producer extends Thread {
    private Container container;
    private int num;
    public Producer(Container s, int num) {
        container=s;
        this.num=num;
    }
    @Override
public void run() {
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        container.mettre(num);
        System.out.println("producer "+i);
        try {
            sleep((long) (Math.random()*100));}
            catch(InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Consumer class:

```
public class Consumer extends Thread {
    private Container container;
    private int num;
    public Consumer(Container s, int num) {
        container=s;
        this.num=num;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int valeur=0;
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            valeur=container.prendre();
            System.out.println("Consumer "+i+" prend "+valeur);
        }
    }

}
```

and this is container class:

```
public class Container {
  private int Contenu;
  private boolean empty= false;
    
  public synchronized int prendre() {
      while(empty==true) {
          try{
              wait();
              }
          catch(InterruptedException e) {}
          }
      empty=true;
      notify();
      return Contenu;
      }
  public synchronized void mettre(int valeur) {
      while(empty==false) {
          try{
              wait();
              }
          catch(InterruptedException e) {}
          }
      Contenu=valeur;
      empty=false;
      notify();
      }
  }
```

When I execute the order of the 2 threads is random, in theory it should be producer then consumer etc.

Comment: I would suggest giving a meaningful name to `D`. What does it represent? Once that is clear, the problem with the logic is clear. The way the code is implemented, `D` represents whether the container is ready to receive a value from the producer. So, it should be initialised to `true`, not `false`.

Comment: Using `wait` and `notify` directly is likely to cause confusion.  It's almost certainly better to use a proper API, like [`Condition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html).

Comment: Each of you methods, `prendre` and `mettre` is establishing the condition the other thread will wait for, immediately after its own wait. Nothing enforces the other thread to wait until the end of the print statement. Hence, you’re not controlling the order of the print statements. To have control over the print order, you’d have to do “wait”, “print”, “change condition and notify” instead of “wait and change condition and notify”, “print”.

Comment: Each of your threads notifies and then prints. Nothing prevents the other thread from catching the notification and then printing before the thread that woke it can print. If you want to order the print statements, you have to print *before* you modify `empty` and release the lock.